# iOS Concurrent Camera Usage

Tags: ios, camera, jailbreak, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am developing a background app that periodically makes use of the camera. This app is for my jailbroken device, so no problem with public SDKs restrictions. I want to take a photo of the different places I go during the day, in an automatic manner.

I am using `AVCaptureSession`, getting the frames from a video in order to produce no sound.

The problem is that if another application wants to make use of the camera (The **Camera** App for instance), and my app tries to take a photo, the **Camera** interface get frozen. Then I need to reopen the Camera app again in order for it to work. I guess it is because the `startRunning` method of the `AVCaptureSession` blocks the usage of previous camera sessions.

Is there any way to use the Camera in shared mode, or *concurrently*?

I don't know if there is some kind of `mixWithOthers` property as is included for the sound compatibility.

Comment: Also, any method to check if the camera is being used would be appreciated. This way, previous to start running the AVCaptureSession my app could wait until the camera is released.

Comment: Looking into private framework IMAVCore, I have found a promising property of the `IMAVCamera` interface, **isSuspended**. However I'm not able to get it working properly. Any suggestion of how to use the interfaces defined in IMAVCamera.h and IMAVCameraController.h??